# is it possible to access the view state from a webflow controller action?

Tags: grails, action, spring-webflow, grails-controller

i have a controller that is not on webflow but need to redirect it to a weblflow. The problem is the view I need to access is inside an action of a webflow.

here is my webflow

class EditSpouseContactInfoController {

```
def index = { redirect(action:"editSpouseContact") }

def editSpouseContactFlow = {

    start{
        action {

           //some codes here
        }

        on("success").to("editSpouseContact")
        on(Exception).to("editSpouseContact")
    }

    editSpouseContact {

        /************************************/
        // Veteran Marital History Processing
        /************************************/
        on("addMaritalHistory"){

            flow.contactInstance.properties = params

            if(!flow.maritalHistoryLst){
                flow.maritalHistoryLst = []
            }
            conversation.maritalHistoryInstance = new MaritalHistory()
            conversation.maritalHistoryInstance.isVeteranMaritalHistory = false


        }.to("editSpouseMaritalHistory")



    }
}
```

here is my non weblow controller:

```
 def addMaritalHistory={
        MySession session = MySession.getMySession(request, params.id)

        def caseInstance = CmCase.get(params.cmCaseIdCmCase.id as Long)
        redirect(controller: "editSpouseContactInfo",  action: "editSpouseContact ", id:caseInstance.id)
    }
```

The line above works but is it possible for me to directly access **addMaritalHistory** inside editSpouseContact?like instead of using the above action it would be action: **"addMaritalHistory"**? Of course it is not working but is there a way to call that as action? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of web flow is that you can't jump directly into the middle of a flow from outside it.  You'll have to add some logic to the initial start state to check for certain parameters in the incoming `params` and jump to the appropriate state from there.